# How to allow null to be added to database

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have an issue where I add data to my database from my WCF application, but I get the following error when stepping over the code snippet below:

> Nullable object must have a value.

```
    foreach (var sectionGroup in quote.Items.First().SectionGroups)
        bills.Add(new ListOfBills
        {
            Cost = (double)sectionGroup.Cost,
            PricePerMeter = sectionGroup.Price_m,
            GroupName = sectionGroup.SectionGroup.Name,
            Length = sectionGroup.Length,
            Quantity = (double)sectionGroup.Quantity,
            StockCode = sectionGroup.StockItem.StockCode,
            StockDescription = sectionGroup.StockItem.Description,
            TruckSection = sectionGroup.SectionGroup.Section,
            Weight = (double)sectionGroup.Weight,
            Width = sectionGroup.Width
        }); 
    return bills;
```

The thing is that from my WPF application where I access the data and display the information in a datagrid, some of the rows will have be ***null*** depending the user's selection from the comboboxes.

So my question is that, is there a way to **not display** the null rows of data or just add them to the database with the value as *null* and how can I get past the nullable error from above?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you ever considered any default value for that spesific data?

Comment: Yes, and it still gave me the same error. :(

Comment: All the information gets collected from the item's **StockCode** and if there is no stock code, all of the data will be null. It's kinda like a VLOOKUP in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use DBNull.Value to represent NULL in DB, so it should solve your error.

In every place you want to add a null add DBNull instead, here's an example:

```
Cost = sectionGroup.Cost == null ? DBNull.Value : (double)sectionGroup.Cost
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Where would I use it?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, please check it out